# Get maximum and minimum value using group by channel id

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I want to get maximum and minimum value using group by channel id and also want to get maximum video id and minimum video id

```
 {

  "query": {
    "term": {
      "channel_id.keyword": {
        "value": "UCQOd1f6pYldvhgvdQ_ktpGA"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "views_max": {
      "max": {
        "field": "views",
        "missing": 0
      },
      "_source":["video_id","views"]
    },
     "views_min": {
      "min": {
        "field": "views",
        "missing": 0
      },
       "_source":["video_id","views"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting some exception on this code  "Expected [START_OBJECT] under [_source], but got a [START_ARRAY] in [views_max]",

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "channel_id.keyword",
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "max": {
            "field": "video_id"
          }
        },
        "3": {
          "min": {
            "field": "video_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "channel_id.keyword": "UCQOd1f6pYldvhgvdQ_ktpGA"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query will give the maximum and minimum of video_id for a particular channel_id.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "channel_id.keyword",
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "max": {
            "field": "video_id"
          }
        },
        "3": {
          "min": {
            "field": "video_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  }
}
```

With the above query, you will be able to fetch for all the distinct channel_id its respective maximum and minimum video_id

Comment: actually i want maximum views and minimum views by channel id and then maximum view video id and minimum views video id

Comment: Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: I want group by one channel_id  and get maximum views and minimum views from the channel id and also want to get maximum record video_id and minimum record video_id